# can't create an object in typescript

Tags: typescript

This is my code:

```
class Animal{
  name: string;

  constructor(theName:string) {
    this.name = theName;
  }
}

let my = new Animal("ACD");
```

This code complies perfectly with out this line "`let my = new Animal("ACD");`"
I get this error when try to create an object

> hello.ts(12,5): error TS1005: ';' expected.

with out object creation part code compile. can anybody help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the error coming from?

Comment: There are only 9 lines here. Your error appears to be on line 12. Can you put this into context?

Comment: You are missing something. There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: i have removed the white spaces that's why.so the error number comes in 9th line.

Comment: please see this image   https://ibb.co/euPFwR

Comment: Perhaps, you should save the changes to the file before you try to re-compile it.

Comment: I will say again, there is nothing wrong with this code. It compiles and runs without error. I also did as you are doing and ran it with ts-node.

Comment: Here is the output of your code with 1 additional `console.log` to print the object: `Chriss-MacBook-Pro:playground lcsharp$ ts-node hello.ts
Animal { name: 'ACD' }`

Comment: @R.Richards agreed. Didn't catch that in his screenshot.

Comment: i have saved it please see this  https://ibb.co/dq1HAm

Comment: @R.Richards That is not the issue. i don't understand the issue . i have saved it and compile again. but same issue  https://ibb.co/dq1HAm

Comment: have you tried running it using `ts-node` rather than tcs?

Comment: also, you are using powershell. can you open a bash shell?

Comment: @ChrisSharp i have saved it and complie again but same issue.https://ibb.co/dq1HAm   .This code should work but don't know what the problem is i am learning typescript these days . this error occurs when try to create the object. please see this screen shothttps://ibb.co/hAEqwR

Comment: One problem with your code is that you're using `let` but you never change the object. Have you tried using `const`? That's appropriate for this.

Comment: @Lewis can you post your tsconfig file? if you are using one

Comment: Here is the file I am running. It is literally a copy and paste of your code. I am even using VS Code. The only difference I can see is that I'm using a bash shell (I don't even have a powershell) https://ibb.co/mizeqm

Comment: works for me also nothing wrong with the code .. may be a config issue

Comment: @Niladri i didnt create an angular project .it is just a ts file. is there a way to find a configuration file. :(

Comment: @ChrisSharp i have tried this code on node terminal  same error .might be a configuration issue but how can i fix this. i have been try to fix this for more than 5 hours . :( i don't know what to do. i want to learn angular that is why im doing typescript first. i'm stuck now. :(. how can i open with bash shell it shows only power shell.

Comment: @Lewis I'm pretty sure your problem is with `tsc`. I get all sorts of random results when I use it on this file. Please `ctrl-c` to stop it and run `ts-node hello.ts`

Comment: @ChrisSharp ts-node hello.ts not working it gives this error .ts-node : The term 'ts-node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ts-node hello.ts

Comment: run `npm install -g ts-node` then close your terminals and reopen and try again.

Comment: @ChrisSharp i ran npm install -g ts-node  .then i close all windows and open and re run ts-node hello.ts now i got this error   Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

Comment: Run this `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisSharp .now it is working.  Thanks again and again. you saved me . :D

Comment: You're welcome. I will write an answer to summarize what we found out. Please accept it so people won't need to read through all of this to find the steps.

Comment: Ok sure Thanks again  @ChrisSharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this in the future, this is a summary of the troubleshooting we did in the comments above to find the problem.

Your code runs fine on my machine, and others, as evidenced above. There seems to be some sort of problem with `tsc`.

Please stop using it and use `ts-node` instead. `ctrl-c` to stop using it and then install `ts-node` (`npm install -g ts-node`) if necessary.

If this causes your machine to complain about Typescript modules then please reinstall Typescript with `npm install -g typescript`

These steps got @Lewis back up again and hopefully, they will save time for others.